# Display RadioButtonList Model Data in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a radiobuttonlist in MVC view Agreement, it displays as a dropdown True/False because the datatype is bit. How do I convert it to radiobuttonlist Yes/No with selected value still bind to the data model value?

HomeController/Index

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View(db.MyTable.ToList());
        }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Agreement)
        </td>

</tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Html.RadioButtonFor` for this purpose. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.radiobutton?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) you can find all overloads and applications.

This is an example:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>item.Agreement,item.Agreement.ToString())
        </td>

    </tr>
}
```

**Update:**

[Here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-radiobutton-radiobuttonfor) you can find additional examples.